# Converting .model file to .Json

Tags: python, json, weka

I have to convert a .model file that has been generated by Weka software in a Json format.

I have searched a lot but i cannot find a solution. Is there any software or maybe a python code that can perform this process? Or maybe if there is a way to output the model in Json from Weka.

Comment: Are you not able to read it as a string? Or does it output weird characters if you try that?

Comment: I have generated a bayesian network model within Weka and i would like to save it in Json format. This Json will be the input for the libpgm library in Python.

This is an example of the format i would like to achive:
https://codeshare.io/UbKVU

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to convert model file to json as there is already a wrapper in python for weka see given link. Using this wrapper you can directly load model files into your python code. https://github.com/willwebberley/WekaPy/blob/master/examples/load_test_model_example.py

```
from wekapy import *

# CREATE NEW MODEL INSTANCE WITH A CLASSIFIER TYPE

model = Model(classifier_type = "bayes.BayesNet")


# LOAD A PREVIOUSLY TRAINED MODEL INTO OUR model OBJECT FOR TESTING AGAINST

model.load_model("/path/to/model.model")
```

Answer (score 0):

Weka's models are serialized Java objects, there is no generic export to JSON.

Bayesian networks can be exported to [XML BIF](http://sites.poli.usp.br/p/fabio.cozman/Research/InterchangeFormat/index.html) using the `GraphVisualizer`, see here:

https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/xml/#bayesian-networks